# ControlM job parameters are not floating while running job

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling, control-m

I created ControlM job with all required parameters(named PARM1, PARM2, PARM3). I able to Order the job and under Monitoring section when i try to run the job the parameters i set while creating job are not passing to script.
May i know why the parameters are not passing to script?

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what kind of Job you are designing?

**Job's type could be determining this behavior.**

It is important to consider this aspect. For example, if the Job type is OS Script then Control-M will send the values ​​of the 3 parameters at the indicated positions. However, if the Job is of type OS Command then you must specify, yourself, those parameters in the command line to execute.

For example, in the **What** specification of the command you should write:

```
thecommnad %%PARM1 %%PARM2 %%PARM3
```